# Reload page once but end up at the top of the page

Tags: javascript

The refresh works properly, but I end up at the bottom of the page. I would like the refresh to keep me at the top of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
//Check if the current URL contains '#'
if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1){
    // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
    url = document.URL+"#";
    location = "#";

    //Reload the page
    location.reload(true);
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: try using jquery **.scrollTop()** api documented at https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0):

Or use plain JS like this:

```html
scroll(0,0)
```